# Why this code using node-schedule is not working?

Tags: node.js

https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-schedule

Code:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.dayOfWeek = [0, 6];
rule.hour = 12;
rule.minute = 25;


var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
    console.log('Yup!');
});

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");

}).listen(port);

console.log("Node server listening on port " + port);
```

I have the started the server from command line so this should print "Yup!" on console at 12.25 but it didn't. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
rule.dayOfWeek = [0, new schedule.Range(1, 6)];
```

Instead of:

```
rule.dayOfWeek = [0, 6]; this one
```